# The fastest way to compare polygons

Tags: algorithm, geometry, spatial, geo

I need to resolve address components of geography point (red).
[image]

Intersection query in mongodb finds me some polygons (see the picture). The green polygon is municipal district, the blue is city and the brown is country. I want to show address as  "Country, City, Municipal district".

The problem is to sort results by size of a polygon. Calculating area by python shapely or multiplying of bounding box sides takes about one second and this is very slow.

What is the fastest way to compare polygons?

Comment: "takes about one second" if your polygons are that huge, what makes you think there's a fast method to compare them?

Comment: How are the polygons defined? If it's just a list of line segments around the perimeter it shouldn't take that long, you can use Green's theorem.

Comment: Polygons defined as geojson. I think that fast method uses in R-Tree index in postgis or mongodb. Millions of bounding boxes per hour calculated in these systems (my speed is thousands per hour).

Comment: Why can't you just precalculate the area of each polygon and store them all in the DB?

Comment: Calculating the area or bounding box of a polygon is a simple operation, and should be faster than parsing geojson in the first place.  Are you sure this is where your program is slow?

Comment: > Why can't you just precalculate the area of each polygon and store them all in the DB

Comment: > Why can't you just precalculate the area of each polygon and store them all in the DB
Because there are 100 000  documents in my DB.  I can calculate area only if it is fast. 
> Calculating the area or bounding box of a polygon is a simple operation
How do you get the bounding box of a polygon?

Answer (score 0):

ST_Area in postgresql calculates  100 000 areas in 1 minute.